# What is the plain alternative to “fossilized language”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was drawn to the word, “fossilized language” appearing in the following sentence of the New York Times’ (June 13) article titled, “Southern politicians try to hold back the tides.”

> “It’s always taken longer to get to the future in the South, and the
>   region’s social tardiness has been on display in this season’s
>   political races. For the moment, at least, harsh and **fossilized
>   language** is still required of both Republican and Democratic
>   candidates (in Mississippi and in Kentucky).”
>   http://takingnote.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/06/03/southern-politicians-try-to-hold-back-the-tides/?hp&rref=opinion

Fossilized language sounds like to me a stale but die-hard slogan. I can imagine what it implies, but I don’t know an exact word to rephrase it briefly.

Google Ngram shows that this word first appeared in early 1900, but the currency is very low (at 0.000000048% level in 2008), after peaking in 1990 (0.000000092).

What is a plain alternative to “fossilized language”? Is it primarily used in political context?

Is it definitely different from “fossil language” such as, say Sanskrit, Coptic and Aram?

Comment: At first glance, I take it to mean *antiquated* within this context.

Comment: It is just a weak metaphor implying that Kentucky is far more primitive than the oh-so-superior New York species of superhumans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the adjective [fossilised](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fossilised) meaning:

> set in a rigidly conventional pattern of behavior, habits, or beliefs; "obsolete fossilized ways"; "an ossified bureaucratic system"
>   fossilized, ossified.

refers to terms and expressions which were used back in time, probably some decades ago, but that are still effective from a political point of view to communicate with that specific electorate. A use of a more contemporary language would not produce the same response with those people.

*Old-fashioned* language may be a more common alternative.

Answer (score 3):

*outdated* language

[outdated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outdated)

> no longer in use or fashionable; out-of-date; outmoded; antiquated.

Answer (score 2):

When used in conjunction with *language*, the word *fossilized* has a special meaning.

[A “fossilized form” as used by linguists](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/hel-lex/2012/paper2835.pdf) means an idiom, word, or even morpheme that has become frozen in time, and so is no longer otherwise meaningful or productive in what should be corresponding situations. It can happen to individual words or to entire phrases.

A few of the scores and perhaps hundreds of possible examples include: *Be that as it may, God save the King, to and fro, short shrift, kith and kin, getting one’s just deserts, run amok, flotsam and jetsam, hither and yon*.

In the broader context of your quote, the fossilized language referred to may well be the empty language of formulaic — and therefore false — courtesy, like *the honorable gentleman* (who is unlikely held to be either) and *by your leave* (because I’ll just go ahead and do it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

[Stilted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/stilted)

> (of behavior, speech, or writing) too formal and not smooth or natural:

Comment: I don't believe the passage is talking about a style of language, but about outdated terminology and attitudes.

Comment: Stars and garters man, you may be right. However, the old often sounds stilted or pompous to us modern types.

Answer (score 0):

> Having been brought up, so to speak, on the grammar and the authors of
>   the golden age of German literature, he began to ask himself the
>   question, whether he **had not misunderstood the teachings of his
>   grammar** and instructors and whether they had not taught him a
>   **fossilized language no longer in vogue.** **Modern language notes**. v.4 1889

The opposit of trendy or vogue is **[marivaudage](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/425838/marivaudage)** language: Preciosity in literary style or expression